# Как прописать путь к изображению в <img src={?}>?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Имеется изображение, и необходимо прописать путь к нему, в `src`. Сам путь передается в компонент через `props`.
 Во-первых,`<img src="./path/img.png">` - если передавать так путь, то изображение не появляется, поэтому использую: `<img src={require("./path/img.png")}>` - если знаете вариант лучше, то буду рад его узнать.
Во-вторых, при передачи в `require` путь из `props` (`<img src={require(this.props.card)}>`), то появляется ошибка `Error: Cannot find module "."`.
 `this.props.card` - 100% является строкой. 
Как быть, как правильно передать путь в `src`?

Comment: Вам нужно понимать что именно браузер читает пусть из src и он совершенно понятия не имеет что вы имеете в виду, когда пишете "./path/blablabla.bla". При подобной записи он (браузер) обращается сюда - http://your-domain.bla/./path/img.png
Require тут скорее правильно чем нет, однако вопрос, чем вы собираете свой проект или вопрос иначе - вы используете какой то фреймворк ?

Comment: @zalex собираю reactjs

Comment: Тут уж лучше подождать того, кто в понимает в реакт, но могу предположить что `{require(this.props.card)}` заставляет искать модуль с именем вашей картинки.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете вызывать `require` не у потомка, а у родителя:

```
<MyComponent imageSrc={require("./image.jpg")} />
```

И использовать уже привычный метод:

```
<img src={this.props.imageSrc} />
```

Comment: Суть в том, что мне не определенный путь к файлу нужен в виде строки засунуть в `require`, а переменную содержащий путь. 
если делать так, как вы советуете, то выглядить оно будет так:
`<MyComponent imageSrc={require(card.img)}`

Answer (score 0):

Забирать путь к файлам можно прямо из "заинтересованного" компонента, а конкретный файл передавать в пропсы.

Родитель:

```
const Toolbar = () => {
    return (
        <div className='toolBar'>
            <div className='tools'>
                <ToolButton image='undo.png' />
                <ToolButton image='redo.png' />
                <ToolButton image='save.png' />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Потомок:

```
const ToolButton = ({ image }) => {
    return (
        <div className='tool-button'>
            <img src={require('../assets/icons/' + image)} alt='' />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

В реакт импортировать нужно изображение

```
Import img "./path/img.png"
```

Потом этот img использовать в src

```
<img src={img}>
```

Это по вопросу как прописать путь к изображению